# Showing characteristic function is infinitely differentiable

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

Suppose that X is a real-valued random variable. Suppose that there exists a constant M > 0 such that the support of X lies entirely in the interval $[-M,M]$. Let $\phi$ denote the characteristic function of X. Show that $\phi$ is infinitely differentiable.

If infinitely differentiable is equivalent to absolutely continuous, then

$$\int_{-M}^{M}| \phi(t)|\;dt < \infty$$

Comment: Infinitely differentiable means derivatives of all orders exist.  It is not equivalent to absolutely continuous.  Because derivatives of $\phi$ correspond to moments of the distribution, you can turn this into a question about the existence of moments of arbitrarily high order.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by support here, but if X lies in $[-M,M]$ a.s. then the following works:

First, have a look at the statement of Theorem 6.6 (pg 107) of: http://stat.uconn.edu/~boba/stat6894/probabilityI.pdf

As X is bounded a.s., $E|X|^k$ is finite for every $k>0$. Hence, by the theorem, 
$\phi^{(k)}(t)$ exists for every $k>0$.

Comment: The link to the theorem does not seem to work

Answer (score 2):

Here is an elementary demonstration that uses only the definition of derivative and the simplest form of Taylor's theorem.  Let's begin, therefore, by quoting these:

> (1) The derivative of a function $f$ at the value $t,$ written $f^\prime(t),$ is any number for which, when $|h|$ is sufficiently small,  $$\left|f(t+h)-f(t) - hf^\prime(t)\right| \le c |h|^2$$ for some number $c$ (not dependent on $h$).

Taylor's Theorem applied to the exponential function states

> (2) Given $M\gt 0$, there exists a number $C_M$ for which $|e^z - 1 - z| \le C_M|z|^2$ for all complex numbers $z$ for which $|z|\le M.$

Let's generalize the question by considering functions $g$ that are integrable and bounded in size on $[-M,M]$ by, say, the number $G.$  Define

$$f_{g,X}(t) = E\left[g(X) e^{itX}\right].$$

Since the support of $X$ is on $[-M,M],$ we may compute all such expectations by integrating from $-M$ to $M.$ Therefore

$$|f_{g,X}(t)| =   \left|E\left[g(X) e^{itX}\right]\right| \le E\left[\left|g(X) e^{itX}\right|\right] = E[G] = G.$$

This shows $f_{g,X}(t)$ exists and is finite for all real $t.$

Write $F$ for the distribution function of $X.$  In the following I will abuse notation by writing (for instance) "$ixg$" for the function $x\to ixg(x).$

Using only linearity of expectation, the inequality $|E[f(X)]| \le E[|f(x)|],$ and algebraic properties of the exponential, we may compute

$$\eqalign{\left|f_{g,X}(t+h) - f_{g,X}(t) - hf_{ixg,X}(t)\right|
& = \left|E\left[g(x)e^{i(t+h)x} -  g(x)e^{itx} - h ixg(x) e^{itx}\right]\right| \\
&= \left|E\left[ixg(x)e^{itx}\left(e^{ihx}-1-ihx\right)\right]\right| \\
&\le E\left[\left|x\right|\left|g(x)\right|\left|e^{ihx}-1-ihx\right|\right] \\
&\le E\left[|x|GC_M\left|ihx\right|^2\right] \\
&= |h|^2 GC_M E\left[|x|^3\right] \\
& \le |h|^2 GC_M M^3.
}$$

Thus, in the definition of the derivative $(1)$ we may take $c=GC_M M^3,$ demonstrating that

> $$f_{g,X}(t)^\prime = f_{ixg, X}(t).$$

By induction on the number of derivatives it is immediate that

$$f_{g,X}(t)^{(n)} = f_{(ix)^n g, X}(t).$$

Applying this to the case $g=1$ shows that $\phi(t) = f_{1,X}$ has derivatives of all orders and that $\phi^{(n)}(t) = f_{(ix)^n, X}(t),$ *QED.*

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic function is

$$\varphi(t) = E[e^{itX}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx}f(x) dx $$

Let's see what happens when we differentiate

$$ \begin{array}{} \frac{d^n}{dt^n} \varphi(t) &=& \frac{d^n}{dt^n}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx}f(x) dx \\
 &=&   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d^n}{dt^n} e^{itx}f(x) dx \\
 &=&   i^n \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx}x^nf(x) dx \\
\end{array} $$

For your case (finite domain) this [exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327099/condition-for-existence-of-fourier-transform) for any $n$ and $t$ since it relates to the Fourier transform of the function $x^nf(x)$ which is integrable (because $f(x)$ is nonzero on a finite domain) and thus exists.

---

A very common expression is for $t=0$

$$ \begin{array}{} \frac{d^n}{dt^n} \varphi(0) &=&  i^n \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^nf(x) dx = i^n E[X^n] \\
\end{array} $$

which expresses the equivalence of the n-th derivative of the characteristic function *in the point zero* with the n-th moment of the variable $X$.

You could reverse this equivalence: If the higher order moments exist (and they exists when the variable is bounded, e.g. from $-M$ to $M$) then the higher order derivatives of the characteristic function must exist.

But, when you relate it to this equivalence expression then this is *only* true for the derivatives of the characteristic function in the point $t=0$.

(Although you could argue more generally for the existence of the derivative *on the entire real line* when higher order moments exist. For instance by arguing that $x^nf(x)$ is an integrable function when the n-th moment exists. But it would be using a somewhat more general property of the characteristic function than the simple equivalence $\frac{d^n}{dt^n} \varphi(0) = i^n E[X^n]$ )